# How to wait for a button to be enabled and click with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer, end-to-end

I have a form with two fields username and password. Once the username is entered the next button is enabled, once I click on it, it shows a password field and once that's entered, it enables the next button again. How do I wait for the button to be enabled in between form updates?

I tried the below approaches, one is commented and the other is not. Both don't work for me.

````
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://localhost:9000/start#!');

await page.type('#login-form-un-field', 'xxxx')
// await page.waitForTarget('#default-next-btn:not([disabled])')
await page.$eval('#default-next-btn:not([disabled])', elem => elem.click());
// const btnNext = await page.$('#default-next-btn');
// btnNext.click();
await page.type('login-form-passcode', '1234');
await page.click('#default-next-btn');
await browser.close();
})();```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit: the button is always present on the page. It is just disabled while form entries are being validated.
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `await page.waitForSelector(selector)` => [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)

your code became:

```
(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:9000/start#!');

    await page.type('#login-form-un-field', 'xxxx')

    await page.waitForSelector('YOUR_SELECTOR_1')
    await page.click('YOUR_SELECTOR_1')

    await page.type('login-form-passcode', '1234');

    await page.waitForSelector('YOUR_SELECTOR_2')
    await page.click('YOUR_SELECTOR_2')

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 30):

To wait for a button (or input) to no longer be disabled, i.e.
`<button id="id" disabled>` use `:not([disabled])` in the selector string passed to **waitForSelector**.

Example:

```
page.waitForSelector('button#id:not([disabled])');
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done it by querying the class list object which returns all the classes including 'disabled'

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#buttonId') 
const isDiabled = await page.evaluate(() =>
      document
        .querySelector('#buttonId')
        .classList.contains('disabled')
    )
```

Once you will have the isDisabled value as false you can proceed to the next steps. This solution is helpful when a tester just wants to create a test to check if the object shown on the screen is disabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I couldn't find any solution. So I'm checking for the button to be enabled repeatedly

```
// Using Typescript but you can remove the Types to make it JS :)

function runRepeatedly(callback: () => Promise<boolean>, options?: TOptions) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let totalTime = 0;
    const interval = options?.interval || 2000;
    const maxLimit = options?.maxLimit || 50000;
    const id = setInterval(async () => {
      const isDisabled = await callback();
      totalTime += interval;
      if (!isDisabled) {
        clearInterval(id);
        resolve();
      }
      if (totalTime === maxLimit) {
        clearInterval(id);
        reject("Max time reached");
      }
    }, interval);
  });
}
```

Here's how you use it

```
try {
    await runRepeatedly(async function () {
      const response = (await page.evaluate(
        `document.querySelector("button").hasAttribute("disabled")`,
      )) as boolean;
      return response;
    });
} catch (err) {
  // Handle the error here 
  console.error("Error", err);
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use `await page.waitFor(selector)`. For more info check the docs [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args)

```
// First you wait for button to appear on screen
await page.waitFor('#default-next-btn');

// Then you click it
await page.click('#default-next-btn');
```